# Is there a way to execute commands in console application of visual studio without it being chosen?

Tags: c, visual-studio, console

I made a program that uses `GetKeyState()` function, but I would want the program to do its thing without me having to chose it (like choose the window of that application, I hope this looks clear and understandable), which means, even if I have another window opened and I have that window chosen, I want my console to do its thing when I press the Key specified.

I don't know if what I said is clear, let's say I'm having chrome opened and I'm surfing through internet pages and I have the console running along side (but its window is not chosen, because I have chrome process chosen, since I'm surfing with it), I want the console program to do its job when I press the Key I stated, while I'm still in chrome (or even while it's minimized).

For example: Discord's overlay and "Push to talk", you can enable/disable overlay, or push to talk while you're in a different program, or even minimized.

Note: I don't need this for a keylogger.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: So you want to make a keylogger, then?

Comment: @molbdnilo No LOL .. I didnt say I want it hidden, all I want is to be able to do stuff or call functions but using my keyboard, but not when I have the program chosen, for example like Discord's overlay, you can enable / disable it while discord isn't chosen or minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is straight forward, tried with VS2017 on Win10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Quit by pressing Ctrl-C");
    for (;;) {
        Sleep(100);
        printf("a=%X R-Ctrl=%X CapsLock=%X\n", GetKeyState('A'), GetKeyState(VK_RCONTROL), GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It produces this output (shortened to make it readable), when keys <kbd>A</kbd>, right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> resp. are pressed and released:

```
Quit by pressing Ctrl-C
a=0 R-Ctrl=0 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=0 CapsLock=0
a=FFFFFF80 R-Ctrl=0 CapsLock=0
a=FFFFFF80 R-Ctrl=0 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=0 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=0 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=FFFFFF81 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=FFFFFF81 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=1 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=1 CapsLock=0
a=0 R-Ctrl=1 CapsLock=FFFFFF81
a=0 R-Ctrl=1 CapsLock=FFFFFF81
a=0 R-Ctrl=1 CapsLock=1
a=0 R-Ctrl=1 CapsLock=1
```

**Edit:**

This works even when another app is topped (in front) or when the console app is minimized.

What you'd like to accomplish is up to you. The test just prints the returned value of GetKeyState(). BTW, if you poll the state too slowly you might miss a key press.